# Wordpress filter

Tags: wordpress, redirect, filter

I need a bit of help with modifying a redirect.

Source code looks like this:

```
$output['redirect_to'] = home_url();
$output['title']       = __( 'Success', 'theme' );
$output['message']     =  __( 'You\'ve been logged in!', 'theme' );
$output = apply_filters( 'login_success_redirect', $output, $save_id, $this->id );
```

This is how I tried to modify the redirect. 
However, it's not working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function new_redirect($new_output) {

    $page_id = 'index.php?page_id=5';
    $new_output['redirect_to'] = home_url('/'.$page_id.'');     
    return $new_output;
}

add_filter( 'login_success_redirect', 'new_redirect', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: What happens if you change `redirect_to` to `get_permalink(5)`?

Comment: you mean like `$new_output['redirect_to'] = get_permalink(5);`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Does it work if you do that?

Comment: No, it didn't :( The link itself isn't a problem; If I were to override the first line of the source code to `$output['redirect_to'] = home_url('/'.$page_id.'');` the redirect works.